# How to construct goals with constraints via MoveIt python binding?

Tags: moveit, python

Is it possible to construct a goal with pose constraints via MoveIt python binding?

I have realized this with

```
moveit_msgs::Constraints pose_goal = kinematic_constraints::constructGoalConstraints("panda_hand_tcp", pose, tolerance_position, tolerance_orientation);
```

where `tolerance_position` and `tolerance_orientation` are both vectors.

But it seems that when using Python binding, `tolerance_position` and `tolerance_orientation` can only be a number instead of an array.

Should I generate the corresponding Python binding based on the Moveit source code?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!